# WebDav uploads fail on files with certain characters on Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, webdav

Have webdav uploads working great on one our boxes but anytime there is a ; # or * (and maybe a few others) the upload fails. That is expected since they're restricted characters but I'm curious if there's a way to rewrite/rename those files on their way through. We don't care what the name is really it just has to make it up to the server. Started looking at mod_rewrite solutions but my rewrite fu is rather weak.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem on the WebDAV client.  These characters should be urlescape()'d before sending to the server.  Can you try a different client and see if it has the same issues?